# Unable to save both user changes when coding during same session

Tags: google-colaboratory

How I understand it, in Colaboratory two people can write code in the same document at the same time. This doesn't seem to be working for us: we are coding in separate sections, but are still struggling to figure out to keep both of our changes. We get the notification below:
"The notebook has been changed outside of this session. Would you like to overwrite existing changes?"

or "Save Failed". Then I get two windows with my edits and his edits, but am unaware how to accept both overides.

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The information I was reading was out-of-date. Google Colaboratory removed the real-time edit functionality:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/355